# How can I change format of number's axis on pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to change format of x or y number in green box of below graph
.[image]

Comment: This is covered in the manual quite extensively. At which point are you stuck?

Comment: In what way? There are lots of ways of altering the formatting, so we need to know what you mean (font, size, decimal places, ...).

Comment: I want change 1o^2 to 100

Comment: possible duplicate of [pgfplots ticklabel format logarithmic scale](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37782/pgfplots-ticklabel-format-logarithmic-scale)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the formatting for an axis using the `every ...` system. For example

```
  \begin{axis}
    [
      every x tick label/.append style  =
        { 
          /pgf/number format/.cd,
           precision = 0, 
           fixed
        }
    ]
```

should I think work here. This works by adding some basic `pgf` number formatting instructions to the end of the code which is used to print the tick labels.

Comment: this approach works well for non-logarithmic axes. Axes with log scale are treated with a different code, in this case, only the exponent is affected by number printing (since many people want an exponent even if it is a real number).

Comment: @Christian. Hmm, in that case my answer is wrong. Would you write an answer and let me know, and I'll delete this one.

Comment: oh, why - simply keep it. It is always good to have a reference for these things.

Answer (score 12):

If you intend to change the formatting of an axis with linear scale (i.e. "normal" numbers), you can proceed as in [Joseph's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54356), i.e. by modifying the keys with `/pgf/number format/` prefix.

Log-axes however require the `log ticks with fixed point` key; it reconfigures `pgfplots` to produces fixed point representation for log axes:

```
\begin{axis}[log ticks with fixed point]
...
```

This style requires the most recent pgfplots stable version 1.5.1

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139084/38080 (linked for the next one searching...)