# Log scale with integer numbers on y-axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm writing a report and one of the requirement of my Bode-plots is that they are logarithmic, but I need integer numbers (i.e. 10, 20 and 30) on the y-axes.

I tried using ytick={} but these numbers do not appear in the graph.

Part of my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    xlabel=frequentie $f (\hertz)$,
    ylabel=weerstand $R (\ohm)$,
    grid=both, 
    minor grid style={gray!25}, 
    major grid style={gray!25},
    ytick={10,15,20,25,30}]
\addplot table[x=f,y=R,col sep=semicolon]{MeetresultatenOpdracht12a.csv};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This should help you out: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139084/21344

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your snippet helps, but it'd be great if you turn it into a complete MWE so that folks don't have to construct anything :) Have you tried `yticklabels={10,15,20,25,30}`?

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses! Oh, I'll mind that next time. I'm quite new to LaTeX and this forum so I still have a lot to learn :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a style example for Bode plots, though you have Ohm as the y-axis unit. In the label computation, `\tick` already holds the logarithmic value depending on the base we have set. Hence if you simply pretty print with the option `fixed` you get the desired value. Otherwise using an exponential function you can convert it to the original value.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
  enlargelimits=false,
  grid=both,
  ymin=5e-6,ymax=2,
  xlabel= Frequency,
  ylabel= R,
  x unit=\si{\hertz},
  y unit=\si{\ohm},
  log basis y=10,
  log basis x=10,
  %dB definition taken as 20 log10(x)
  yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{20*(\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfmathresult}},
  domain=1e-7:1e1,samples=250
]
\addplot+[no marks,thick]{exp(-5*x)};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This achieves the desired result, but scientifically is very wrong. Units should be marked as "dB" and for dB units, the yscale is linear, using a logarithmic grid is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the bodegraph package (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bodegraph)

Some example here (http://sciences-indus-cpge.papanicola.info/Bode-Black-et-Nyquist-avec-Tikz)  and here http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/bode-plot/