# Problems with bode diagram (representing an image)

Tags: diagrams

I need help to represent this image (I needed this because I must represent the bode diagram):

[image]

I know how to represent bode diagram, for example if we have the transfer function

```
H = tf([1 0.1 7.5],[1 0.12 9 0 0]);
bode(H,{0.1,10}))
```

but I have problems to represent that image. There are magnitudes and that dots and I don't know how to do that. I don't know if I can do that in MatLab or in LaTeX...

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163122/log-scale-with-integer-numbers-on-y-axes?s=4|0.3660  Adding phase is trickier, but should be possible.

Comment: can you explain your function with laplace variable

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Bodegraph package
I assume you want to plot this example
http://fr.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/bode.html

[image]

it is necessary to set the transfer function of the form

[image]

with

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{bodegraph}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=15/4]
\begin{scope}[yscale=3/60]
\UnitedB
\semilog{-1}{2}{-60}{60}

\BodeGraph[thick,samples=500]{-1:2}
{-\SOAmp{7.5}{0.0182}{2.73}+
\SOAmp{9}{0.02}{3}+
2*\IntAmp{1}
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm,yscale=3/90]
\UniteDegre
\OrdBode{15}
\semilog{-1}{2}{-180}{0}
\BodeGraph[thick,samples=500]{-1:2}
{-\SOArg{7.5}{0.0182}{2.73}+
\SOArg{9}{0.02}{3}+
2*\IntArg{1}
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

with a zoom

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{bodegraph}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=15/1]
\begin{scope}[yscale=3/60]
\UnitedB
\semilog{-0}{1}{-60}{60}

\BodeGraph[thick,samples=500]{0:1}
{-\SOAmp{7.5}{0.0182}{2.73}+
\SOAmp{9}{0.02}{3}+
2*\IntAmp{1}
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm,yscale=3/90]
\UniteDegre
\OrdBode{15}
\semilog{-0}{1}{-180}{0}
\BodeGraph[thick,samples=500]{0:1}
{-\SOArg{7.5}{0.0182}{2.73}+
\SOArg{9}{0.02}{3}+
2*\IntArg{1}
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

more info : [Plot a transfer function in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286407/plot-a-transfer-function-in-latex/286492#286492)