# Bodegraph - How do I convert transfer function coefficients into parsable arguments?

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, bodegraph

I need help understanding how the conversion explained in  [Problems with bode diagram (representing an image)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284988/problems-with-bode-diagram-representing-an-image) is done.

Here it is explained that the transfer function is needed on a specific form, namely one that fits into one of the amp/phase functions as described within the [bodegraph.sty package](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/bodegraph/bodegraph.sty):

Also [here is a link](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/bodegraph/bodegraph.pdf) to the description of the package itself (OBS: contains french with minimal english)

My question herein lies, how would i convert the following 2nd order transfer function into something that bodegraph can take as an argument for plotting both the magnitude and phase.

[image: Transfer function]

Which has the following bodeplot

[image: Bode plot]

After trying myself by utilizing the following (taken from bodegraph package description)

[image: Second order transform]

I get the following parameters for my transfer function after normalization:

[image: Parameters]

These parameters together with the following output from tikz produce the wrong bodeplot, i've tried using the same function as described in the first link, however i still find the output to be wrong.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',
    ref lines/.style={thin, blue!60},
    ref points/.style={circle, black, opacity=0.7, fill, minimum size= 3pt, inner sep=0},
    every node/.style={font=\small},
    bode lines/.style={very thick, blue},
    Gclabel/.style={text=blue},
    xscale=15/5,
    gnuplot def/.style={samples=50,id=\arabic{idGnuplot},prefix=gnuplot/\jobname },
    semilog lines/.style={thin, black!100},
    semilog lines 2/.style={thin, black!20, dashed},
    semilog half lines/.style={semilog lines 2, dashed },
    Black lines/.style={very thick, blue},
    Black grid/.style={ultra thin,brown},
    Black abaque mag/.style={gray,ultra thin,dashed,smooth},
    Black abaque phase/.style={gray,ultra thin,smooth},
    Black label points/.style={font=\tiny},
    Black label axes/.style={Black grid, font=\tiny},
    Nyquist lines/.style={very thick, blue},
    Nyquist grid/.style={ultra thin,brown},
    Nyquist label axes/.style={Nyquist grid,font=\tiny},
    Nyquist label points/.style={font=\tiny},
    Temp lines/.style={very thick, blue},
    Temp grid/.style={ultra thin,brown},
    Temp label axes/.style={Temp grid, font=\tiny},
    Temp label points/.style={font=\tiny},
    Abaque grid/.style={ultra thin,brown!80},
    Abaque lines/.style={thick, blue,smooth}
    ]
\begin{scope}[yscale=1/50]
\UnitedB
\OrdBode{50}
\semilog{-2}{3}{-100}{150}
\BodeGraph[thick,samples=1000]{-2:3}
{\SOAmp{59.37351685}{1.538057009}{45.90206967}}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm,yscale=3/90]
\UniteDegre
\OrdBode{20}
\semilog{-2}{3}{-180}{0}
\BodeGraph[thick,samples=500]{-2:3}
{ \SOArg{59.37351685}{1.538057009}{45.90206967}}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output

[image]

Comment: You can find the needed arguments by comparing your transfer function to the form in the question you are referring to. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Not sure if it is helpful, but see also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286407/plot-a-transfer-function-in-latex).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've already looked at that question and didnt really get a better clue. However i do think i've understood how i should compare the transfer functions after further reading, it would still be nice with some clarification however.

Comment: Your first example is wrong, see the plot by WolframAlpha (Mathematica)
(copy and paste all the link
========
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bodeplot&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22BodePlotCalculator%22,+%22transferfunc%22%7D+-%3E%221.251e5%2F(2017%2B141.2*s%2Bs%5E2)%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22bodeplot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Formula%22%7D&rawformassumption=%7B%22MC%22,%22%22%7D-%3E%7B%22Formula%22%7D
========

Comment: the first example of the transfer function is the same type as the latter
H (s) = (1 + s * 100) / (s ^ 2 * (1 + 10 * s))

==========

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bodeplot&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22BodePlotCalculator%22,+%22transferfunc%22%7D+-%3E%22(1%2B100*s)%2F(s%5E2*(1%2B10*s))%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22bodeplot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Formula%22%7D&rawformassumption=%7B%22MC%22,%22%22%7D-%3E%7B%22Formula%22%7D

================

Comment: I'm not quite sure you links works as intended, however you have found my error! Oh my god, how stupid can a man be. I had for some reason been looking at the wrong bodeplot from matlab. ahahah, thanks! :)

Comment: Is it possible to add higher order transfer functions that dosent contain any integrators? example: (7682*s^2+0.7682e7*s+5364)/(s^5+2874*s^4+0.3882e6*s^3+0.3257e7*s^2-0.6249e8*s-0.3871e9)

Comment: If possible, i have a problem concerning: 

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302982/bodegraph-plotting-higher-order-transfer-function