# pgfplots log axis to show linear style tick labels

Tags: pgfplots, labels, ticks

I have created a `semilogxaxis` to plot my data, however I have problems showing the ticks on the x-axis the way I want. At the moment, the `ticklabels` are shown in the 10^n notation, however I prefer the way they are shown in the linear axis. In the linear axis they are shown as values, scaled some fixed power.

My first try was to set `log ticks with fixed point` and turning on scaling using `scaled x ticks=true`. However `pgfplots` fails to scale the numbers and just shows the full numbers.

Does anyone have a solution for having the for me more pleasing linear scaled xtick labels in a (semi)log axis?

My axis code:

```
 \begin{semilogxaxis}[
    clip mode=individual,
    xmin=2.5e5, xmax=1.45e6,
    ymin=0.021,ymax=0.033,
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis on top=true,
    xlabel=$\text{Re}_\text{i}$,
    ylabel=$\text{C}_\text{f}$,
    legend pos=south west,
    legend style={draw=none, 
                  % font=,
                  fill=none,
                 },
    legend cell align=left,
    reverse legend,
    width = 6.2cm,
    height = 5.7cm,
    ylabel near ticks, 
    log ticks with fixed point,
    scaled x ticks=true,
    % load a color `cycle list' from the `colorbrewer' library
    cycle list/Dark2-4,
    % mark list fill={.!75!white},  define fill color for the marker
    % create new `cycle list` from existing `cycle list's and an
    cycle multiindex* list={
        Dark2-4
            \nextlist
        my marks
            \nextlist
        [3 of]linestyles
            \nextlist
        very thick
            \nextlist
    }
  ]
```

[image: Result with not so nice xticklabels]

Comment: like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139079/pgfplots-log-ticks-with-fixed-point-only-for-one-axis or this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163122/log-scale-with-integer-numbers-on-y-axes?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: @percusse thanks for your answer. I found the first one, which helpt me get the same result as 'log ticks with fixed point', but I do not seem to get the scaled version working to get e.g. 0.2, 0.4, .. 1.4 \cdot 10^6.