# Removing scientific notation of y-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, matlab, matlab2tikz

Hello fellows and folks!

I am having a very hard time trying to figure out how to remove the scientific notations on the y-axis of my graphs. The graphs are made in MATLAB and then converted into TikZ files using the package `matlab2tikz`.

This is the MATLAB plot I want to reproduce in LaTeX:

[image]

I tried to follow the solution of [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119887/remove-the-scientific-notation-which-is-unreasonable)

All i did was to add this code to my `My_Picture.tikz`

```
\begin{axis}[ 
  ... ,
  scaled y ticks = false, 
  y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill,precision=3}
  ]
```

It seems not to have any effect on my plot, see picture:

[image: Scientific notation y-axis]

The code of the plot:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{1.00000,0.00000,1.00000}%

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.85\textheight,
height=0.85\textwidth,
at={(0\textwidth,0\textwidth)},
scale only axis,
xmode=log,
xmin=100,
xmax=10000000,
xminorticks=true,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={Schwingspielzahl N [-]},
ymode=log,
ymin=200,
ymax=1000,
yminorticks=true,

% ADDED CODE
scaled y ticks = false, 
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill,precision=3},
% ADDED CODE

ylabel={$\text{Nennspannungsamplitude S}_\text{a}\text{ [MPa]}$},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
legend style={at={(0.03,0.03)}, anchor=south west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=blue]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
643069.570404222    280\\
524615.364995537    292.203389830508\\
431560.950185276    304.406779661017\\
357747.705880378    316.610169491525\\
298670.922324037    328.813559322034\\
250995.402712107    341.016949152542\\
212223.953210292    353.220338983051\\
180467.2473652  365.423728813559\\
154281.939122341    377.627118644068\\
132555.376571843    389.830508474576\\
114422.556012061    402.033898305085\\
99205.6563837048    414.237288135593\\
86369.5708609478    426.440677966102\\
75488.8941545569    438.64406779661\\
66223.1965817789    450.847457627119\\
58298.3497797543    463.050847457627\\
51492.3115530138    475.254237288136\\
45624.2243224967    487.457627118644\\
40545.9957005785    499.661016949153\\
36135.7524991303    511.864406779661\\
32292.7189490448    524.067796610169\\
28933.1850455344    536.271186440678\\
25987.3147398867    548.474576271186\\
23396.605174772 560.677966101695\\
21111.8535903039    572.881355932203\\
19091.5223371242    585.084745762712\\
17300.4177629025    597.28813559322\\
15708.6178383203    609.491525423729\\
14290.5978789259    621.694915254237\\
13024.5147773098    633.898305084746\\
11891.618646451 646.101694915254\\
10875.7673231048    658.305084745763\\
9963.02425873755    670.508474576271\\
9141.32428412254    682.71186440678\\
8400.19483410961    694.915254237288\\
7730.52265851903    707.118644067797\\
7124.35797302353    719.322033898305\\
6574.74953405236    731.525423728814\\
6075.60534124647    743.728813559322\\
5621.57464676087    755.932203389831\\
5207.94773446141    768.135593220339\\
4830.57056392104    780.338983050847\\
4485.77188535148    792.542372881356\\
4170.30084667368    804.745762711864\\
3881.27345205551    816.949152542373\\
3616.1265075861 829.152542372881\\
3372.5779163145 841.35593220339\\
3148.59237119098    853.559322033898\\
2942.35164811614    865.762711864407\\
2752.22882840933    877.966101694915\\
2576.7658854377 890.169491525424\\
2414.65415783431    902.372881355932\\
2264.71730485459    914.576271186441\\
2125.89640055241    926.779661016949\\
1997.23687469073    938.983050847458\\
1877.87705134521    951.186440677966\\
1767.03807240581    963.389830508475\\
1664.01502377477    975.593220338983\\
1568.16910793809    987.796610169491\\
1478.9207285269 1000\\
};
\addlegendentry{$\text{Originaldaten P}_{\text{RAM}}$}

\addplot [color=blue, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
643069.570404222    280\\
10000000    280\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor1]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
588787.647699664    280\\
482675.7675395  292.203389830508\\
398918.238649259    304.406779661017\\
332174.413660816    316.610169491525\\
278519.857785052    328.813559322034\\
235036.112551315    341.016949152542\\
199528.686533166    353.220338983051\\
170330.442663494    365.423728813559\\
146162.720527769    377.627118644068\\
126036.041279993    389.830508474576\\
109178.305184302    402.033898305085\\
94982.3175424476    414.237288135593\\
82967.0582469189    426.440677966102\\
72748.8283184884    438.64406779661\\
64019.5658641829    450.847457627119\\
56530.4152435643    463.050847457627\\
50079.1796377678    475.254237288136\\
44500.6685175824    487.457627118644\\
39659.2202703828    499.661016949153\\
35442.871487675 511.864406779661\\
31758.781720955 524.067796610169\\
28529.621936798 536.271186440678\\
25690.7074780488    548.474576271186\\
23187.7097245715    560.677966101695\\
20974.8202061218    572.881355932203\\
19013.2704379205    585.084745762712\\
17270.1329220858    597.28813559322\\
15717.3455192656    609.491525423729\\
14330.9141425241    621.694915254237\\
13090.2584773636    633.898305084746\\
11977.6729334877    646.101694915254\\
10977.8808356357    658.305084745763\\
10077.6643708827    670.508474576271\\
9265.55633309366    682.71186440678\\
8531.58247071988    694.915254237288\\
7867.04542474299    707.118644067797\\
7264.3429705744 719.322033898305\\
6716.81465126351    731.525423728814\\
6218.61198626822    743.728813559322\\
5764.58831946853    755.932203389831\\
5350.20507786087    768.135593220339\\
4971.4517840645 780.338983050847\\
4624.7776292017 792.542372881356\\
4307.03278967432    804.745762711864\\
4015.41797900605    816.949152542373\\
3747.44097780603    829.152542372881\\
3500.8790917859 841.35593220339\\
3273.74665818598    853.559322033898\\
3064.26686177183    865.762711864407\\
2870.8472382289 877.966101694915\\
2692.05833971511    890.169491525424\\
2526.61511808347    902.372881355932\\
2373.36064873534    914.576271186441\\
2231.25187454354    926.779661016949\\
2099.34709669489    938.983050847458\\
1976.79497919347    951.186440677966\\
1862.82486741172    963.389830508475\\
1756.73824951641    975.593220338983\\
1657.90121369105    987.796610169491\\
1565.73777453178    1000\\
};
\addlegendentry{$\text{Originaldaten P}_{\text{RAJ}}$}

\addplot [color=blue, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
588787.647699664    280\\
10000000    280\\
};
\addplot [color=red]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
162197.790175605    280\\
134276.597075491    292.203389830508\\
112024.508428368    304.406779661017\\
94128.0567876752    316.610169491525\\
79613.0805836353    328.813559322034\\
67748.6450082955    341.016949152542\\
57980.3989468891    353.220338983051\\
49883.7096482158    365.423728813559\\
43130.2828973797    377.627118644068\\
37464.1048043433    389.830508474576\\
32683.9094456293    402.033898305085\\
28630.2696295897    414.237288135593\\
25175.9993699367    426.440677966102\\
22218.9534520572    438.64406779661\\
19676.579101227 450.847457627119\\
17481.7601359599    463.050847457627\\
15579.6228553119    475.254237288136\\
13925.0634292966    487.457627118644\\
12480.8207746208    499.661016949153\\
11215.9648744374    511.864406779661\\
10104.7037108799    524.067796610169\\
9125.43616869024    536.271186440678\\
8259.99602762757    548.474576271186\\
7493.04529847453    560.677966101695\\
6811.58494536393    572.881355932203\\
6204.55837974634    585.084745762712\\
5662.52865559696    597.28813559322\\
5177.41450804644    609.491525423729\\
4742.27359752756    621.694915254237\\
4351.12379677168    633.898305084746\\
3998.79527122537    646.101694915254\\
3680.80759007252    658.305084745763\\
3393.26726600503    670.508474576271\\
3132.78203292208    682.71186440678\\
2896.38888898941    694.915254237288\\
2681.49350129295    707.118644067797\\
2485.81902071724    719.322033898305\\
2307.3627169899 731.525423728814\\
2144.35913355615    743.728813559322\\
1995.24869516546    755.932203389831\\
1858.65088948852    768.135593220339\\
1733.34129688501    780.338983050847\\
1618.23186678289    792.542372881356\\
1512.35394065065    804.745762711864\\
1414.84360470444    816.949152542373\\
1324.929023828  829.152542372881\\
1241.91946450961    841.35593220339\\
1165.19576116559    853.559322033898\\
1094.20201882626    865.762711864407\\
1028.438377258  877.966101694915\\
967.454688353053    890.169491525424\\
910.844980984985    902.372881355932\\
858.242606270006    914.576271186441\\
809.31597191935 926.779661016949\\
763.76478762695 938.983050847458\\
721.316754628175    951.186440677966\\
681.724642033715    963.389830508475\\
644.76370057079 975.593220338983\\
610.229371185592    987.796610169491\\
577.935251769825    1000\\
};
\addlegendentry{Versuch}

\addplot [color=red, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
162197.790175605    280\\
10000000    280\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

I tried to hard code the yticks `ytick={200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000}`, but that did not work out.

[image]

i tried also adding `yticklabels={200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000}` with this outcome:

[image]

Comment: ytick={...} specifies the values, not the format.  You need yticklabels={...}.  See page 340-341 of manual.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried changing it to yticklabels but it is incorrect, see screenshot.

Comment: You need to both, as the default ytick values are 223.87 etc.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139079/pgfplots-log-ticks-with-fixed-point-only-for-one-axis

Comment: thank you, it worked!