# Show coordinates on axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I show the coordinates of the listed points on a Pgfplots log-log diagram?

Also, how can I label each graph given by a table with a different name?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmode=log, 
ymode=log, 
xlabel=Processors, 
ylabel=Speedup
]

\addplot table {
1 1
2 1.99892449476752
4 3.96674166623464
8 7.88161642065569
16 15.4344468776274
32 12.4017223883252
64 24.0354227021333
};

\addplot table {
1 1
2 1.99804684248206
4 5.34549214847199
8 7.94496112836762
16 15.7551224031058
32 22.774653408508
64 40.4820003069663
};

\addplot table {
1 1
2 2.00359505426647
4 3.87681649751088
8 7.94921166729328
16 15.7830470707627
32 28.9132497101297
64 56.1481274839776
};

\addplot table {
1 1
2 1.99397507855784
4 3.98192544925128
8 7.98048783262623
16 15.8061179993891
32 30.4545364844811
64 59.9506057736665
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is an example on the coordinates marked in the x axis:

[image]

Ideally something similar should be achieved in the y axis but I'm not sure if the points are two close it will be difficult to make the difference.

Comment: Are you after some version of `nodes near coords`? As for the labeling, I don't really understand what you mean at all.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. the diagram plots different tables, the idea is put a name to each of the graphs representing these tables.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. nodes near coords seems to show points on the graph, I want the points on the axis themselves

Comment: For the labeling, sounds like you're after a legend. For example add `\legend{a,b,c,d}` inside the `axis` environment, and possibly `legend pos=north west` in the `axis` options.  See manual for details. For the other, perhaps I'm slow, but how exactly do you want this to look? Perhaps a quick sketch made in Paint or similar would help.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I added an example with the coordinates marked on the x axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether there exists an easier way than that suggested in [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139084/47927), but using this approach you can do:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmode=log, 
ymode=log, 
xlabel=Processors, 
ylabel=Speedup,
xtick={data},
xticklabel={%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
    \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed relative, precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
},
]

\addplot table {
1 1
2 1.99892449476752
4 3.96674166623464
8 7.88161642065569
16 15.4344468776274
32 12.4017223883252
64 24.0354227021333
};

\addplot table {
1 1
2 1.99804684248206
4 5.34549214847199
8 7.94496112836762
16 15.7551224031058
32 22.774653408508
64 40.4820003069663
};

\addplot table {
1 1
2 2.00359505426647
4 3.87681649751088
8 7.94921166729328
16 15.7830470707627
32 28.9132497101297
64 56.1481274839776
};

\addplot table {
1 1
2 1.99397507855784
4 3.98192544925128
8 7.98048783262623
16 15.8061179993891
32 30.4545364844811
64 59.9506057736665
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]