# y minor ticks not showing with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks

I want some minor ticks on the y axis, but it doesn't work. I already tried minor y ticks num but it didn't help. Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside ]{article}
\usepackage[USenglish, german,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm,left=1cm , right =1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
            xmin = 0,
            height=10cm,
            width=18cm,
            ymode=log,
            grid = both,
          ]

  coordinates{
   (1,2)(2,4)(3,6)(4,8)(5,10)(6,12)(7,14)(8,16)(9,18)(10,20) 
  };

  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but that is not what I meant. For example the following pictures from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37782/pgfplots-ticklabel-format-logarithmic-scale ,... here you see major an minor ticks, and that is not happening in my example above :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `minor y tick num` key is not available for logarithmic axis (see manual version 1.10, page 276)

But if you enlarge the range of your y axis you will get the minor ticks or grid. Use something like `enlarge y limits=0.4`to get

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside ]{article}
\usepackage[USenglish, german,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm,left=1cm , right =1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
            xmin = 0,
            height=10cm,
            width=18cm,
            ymode=log,
            grid = both,
            major y grid style=red,
            enlarge y limits=.4
          ]
\addplot  coordinates{
   (1,2)(2,4)(3,6)(4,8)(5,10)(6,12)(7,14)(8,16)(9,18)(10,20) 
  };

  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Or if you want minor ticks instead of the minor grid you can use

```
grid = major,
minor y tick style={red,very thick},
enlarge y limits=.4
```

[image]

Alternativly you can set `ymin=1,ymax=100` to enlarge the y range:

```
grid = major,
minor y tick style={red,very thick},
ymin=1,ymax=100
```

[image]

If you don't want a larger y range you can use the key `ytickten={0,...,10}` to set the major ticks explicitly only at 10^0,10^1,...,10^10.Then there will be only one major y line at 10^1 in your example.

```
grid = both,
major y grid style=red,
ytickten={0,...,10}
```

[image]

Comment: I think in your first sentence it should read `minor y tick num` (no plural s)

Answer (score 3):

The ticks *are* being placed but are being obscured by  the grid. So you can either disable the grid, or change the style of the ticks so that they are more prominent:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside ]{article}
\usepackage[USenglish, german,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm,left=1cm , right =1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
            xmin = 0,
            height=10cm,
            width=18cm,
            ymode=log,
            grid = both,
            y tick style={ultra thick, draw=red},
            x tick style={ultra thick, draw=blue},
          ]

  coordinates{
   (1,2)(2,4)(3,6)(4,8)(5,10)(6,12)(7,14)(8,16)(9,18)(10,20) 
  };

  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: also thanks for the quick answer, but I am looking for the minor ticks. Like here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37782/pgfplots-ticklabel-format-logarithmic-scale there some small ticks between the big ticks ,.. sorry if my explanation was confusing